# I send action to my router(d-link) with libupnp, UPNP_E_BAD_HTTPMSG occur

Tags: upnp

I successful register upnp-client and download the service description.

But when i send action "GetTotalBytesSent", the UPNP_E_BAD_HTTPMSG error was returned.

My wifi-router has a password. Is there any relation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure it has some relationship between router passwd and upnp.

I try miniupnp to modify the port mapping with no router password, and it's worked. So i suppose that there was no relationship!